# queryset filter between 2 values whit foreing keys?

Tags: django-queryset

I have problems with the following queryset, I probe it in django shell and it returns an empty list.

The situation is that I'm occupying a lforeing key, I did the same exercise with the model "Tarifa_Sem" and returns the value without any problem, just replace the F ('') by a variable x = 1000

The situation is that the table of the model "Tarifa_Sem" is only for consultation.

Where I am going to manage and save the response of the queryset is in the "Calculadora_isr" model

Model 1

```
class Tarifa_Sem(models.Model):
limite_inferior_isr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
limite_inferior_subsidio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
limite_superior = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Model 2

```
class Calculadora_isr(models.Model):
tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa_Sem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
base_gravada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
limite_inf_calculo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
```

Queryset and save()

```
def limite_inferior(self):
    queryset = Calculadora_isr.objects.filter(tarifa__limite_superior__gte=F('base_gravada'),tarifa__limite_inferior_isr__lte=F('base_gravada')).distinct().values('tarifa__limite_inferior_isr')
    return queryset

def save(self):
    self.limite_inf_calculo = self.limite_inferior
    super (Calculadora_isr, self).save()
```

In the shell of django the list appears empty.

```
>>> queryset = Calculadora_isr.objects.filter(tarifa__limite_superior__gte=F('base_gravada'),tarifa__limite_inferior_isr__lte=F('base_gravada')).distinct().values('tarifa__limite_inferior_isr')
```

And in the admin when I give him save he tells me:

conversion from method to Decimal is not supported

thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

To solve the problem of passing the "base_gravada" field, use another variable that returns all the values ​​of "base_gravada"

```
qs1 = Calculadora_isr.objects.values_list('base_gravada')
```

And in my second query, use the variable qs1:

```
qs2 = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(limite_superior__gte=qs1,limite_inferior_isr__lte=qs1).distinct().values('limite_inferior_isr')
```